# Ordinate Dimension Text Position

Tags: c#, revit-api

I'm looking for a workaround to be able to edit the property `TextPosition` or move the label of an Ordinate Dimension. I'm aware the RevitAPIDocs clearly say that it's not possible :

> This property (TextPosition) is not applicable to all dimensions. For example, it is not available for spot slope dimensions, multi-segments dimensions, dimensions using equality formula, and **when dimension style is ordinate**.

I wonder if any or you know a way to move the `TextPosition` anyway in case of overlaping labels.

I tried to search in the document for other elements representing the labels but can't find any.